# Response.redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010 asp.net website.
I made an aspx. page called forgetpassword.aspx and added a button with the codes

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Redirect("company.aspx");
  }
```

I even tried:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Redirect("company.aspx", true);
  }
```

However, the page remains the same, the button is unable to redirect to company.aspx. I suspect there could be something wrong with my master page, but I am not sure. Please advise!

Here is my master page:

```
   <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"        CodeFile="Master.master.cs" Inherits="Master" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <title>  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
   <title>Home | Triangle</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->       
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png"></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </head>
 <body></body>
  </html>
```

Here is the source view (html) of my forgetpassword.aspx page:

```
   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="forgetpassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"   Runat="Server">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
  </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you share code for button1.Click event

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with master page?  Can you show us full click event code?

Comment: I editied it! Please take a look!

Comment: Please check my answer :)

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside that click handler and see if it gets hit? In other words: is the problem that the redirect "doesn't work" or that the handler doesn't execute?

Comment: What is "doesn't work" exactly? You don't get redirected at all, or you get redirected to a wrong page or get a 404 response?

Comment: The page stays the same, as it is. It doesn't go to any page, it doesn't show any error page, as though nothing happened at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the path, as the way shown in `MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"`.

```
Response.Redirect("~/company.aspx");
```

**EDIT**

You need to use same `ContentPlaceHolder` ID across all the files, by default it is `MainContent`.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And also make sure to place your `Button` inside a `form`.

```
<form action="/" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

Now the redirect should work.

Comment: if your company.aspx is inside a folder.. u need to specify that too, like "~/views/company.aspx". "~/" is the root of your application.

Comment: they are both in the same folder

Comment: it doesn't work, there is error when i change the container id

Comment: use same container id in all the files.. container in Master file is referenced in all other files. so you should stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

redirect should take a url as a parameter however you are only passing a string "company.aspx". Please try this

```
Response.Redirect(~/(path)/company.aspx);
```

Replace path with correct file path in your project

Comment: Copy of abdul's answer.

Comment: What is the complete path of company.aspx file ?

Comment: It says "invalid expression '/' ". I then tried adding the aspostrophe, but clicking the button doesn't redirect me to company.aspx either

Comment: You need quotes (") around that string.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a redirect use

```
PostBackUrl="company.aspx"
```

like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="company.aspx"/>
```

This will avoid need of calling event from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (Response.IsClientConnected)
         {
            // If still connected, redirect
            // to another page. 
            Response.Redirect("company.aspx", false);
         }
      }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will not *make* the redirect work, just *prevent* it in some cases (that probably will not happen in this simple handler).